# Call make on a FreeBSD port outside the port's directory

Tags: makefile, port, freebsd, cd

Can `make` be called on a FreeBSD port outside of the port's directory? I.e. without the use of the `cd` command.

To contextualise, whilst the following can be done :`cd /usr/ports/www/apache24 && sudo make config-recursive install distclean`, something like this pseudocode would be preferred: `sudo make config-recursive install distclean -p /usr/ports/www/apache24`

Thank you

Comment: Does the `-C` argument to make help you here? `make -C /usr/ports/www/apache24 config-recursive install distclean`?

Comment: Yes, great thank you. If you want to put this as an answer so I can mark it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [`-C` option](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)) of `make` is for.

> ```
> -C directory
>      Change to directory before reading the makefiles or doing any-
>      thing else.  If multiple -C options are specified, each is inter-
>      preted relative to the previous one: -C / -C etc is equivalent to
>      -C /etc.
> ```

So you want to use this:

```
make -C /usr/ports/www/apache24 config-recursive install distclean
```